# SonarQube permissions location

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to config a **SonarQube** server using puppet.

My puppet manifests install software, deploy my custom sonar.properties, deploy ssl certificates, download and configure few plugins and, at last,  start service.

Default **Global Permissions** allows **Execute Analysis** and **Execute Preview Analysis** to Anyone.

Default **Project Permissions** allows **Browse** and **See Source Code** to Anyone.

I want change this from my puppet code without using the web interface. Not only before first deploy. In each repuppet I could want change this permissions.

The goal is config and reconfig SonarQube in automatic way.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: The database is not an API. So, you won't find that information. Could you please describe your use case?

Comment: I rewrite the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please open a new thread for the password encryption? Thanks.

Comment: Of Course. By the way, I can't vote up your answer. I haven't enough reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update permissions, you can do it through web service calls: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=231735777